# How to select multiple columns grouping by with only one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to retrieve all the data of emp detail table grouping by class_ no based on max(created_at). Also I don't want to group by data with any other column as it changes the final result.
Also, Is there any solution to retrieve the same result without even using group by clause

```
create table emp
(
   emp_id serial primary key,
   emp_no integer,
   emp_ref_no character varying(15),
   emp_class character varying(15),
   created_at timestamp,
   created_by character varying(20)
);

create table emp_detail
(
   emp_detail_id serial primary key,
   emp_id integer,
   class_no integer,
   col1 JSONB,
   col2 JSONB,
   col3 JSONB,
   created_at timestamp without time zone default now(),
   created_by character varying(20),
   constraint con_fk foreign key(emp_id) references emp(emp_id)
 );

INSERT INTO emp(
            emp_no, emp_ref_no, emp_class, created_by)
    VALUES ('548251', '2QcW', 'abc', 'Nik');

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 1, '2018-05-04 11:00:00', 
            'Nik'); 

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 1, '2018-04-04 11:00:00', 
            'Nik'); 

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 2, '2018-05-10 11:00:00', 
            'Nik');

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 2, '2018-02-01 11:00:00', 
            'Nik');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (ed.class_no) ed.*
from emp_detail ed
order by ed.class_no, created_at desc;
```

`distinct on` is a very handy Postgres extension.  This is probably the fastest method, especially with an index on `emp_detail(class_no, created_at desc)`.

Other alternatives are a subquery with `row_number()` or a correlated subquery.

Comment: You are genius!